Gitlab CICD test stage with aws cli command
We are testing our AWS Serverless lambdas in a test stage in Gitlab CICD.
Everything worked fine until a week ago.
This is the stage definition :
"Test":
  image: docker:latest
  services:
    - name: amazon/dynamodb-local
      alias: dynamodb
    - name: localstack/localstack
      alias: localstack
  stage: test
  only:
    - merge_requests
    - main
  variables:
    <<: *test_variables
  coverage: /All files[^|]*\|[^|]*\s+([\d\.]+)/
  dependencies:
    - "Build"
  before_script:
    - apk --update add nodejs npm
    - apk add --no-cache aws-cli
  script:
    - node --version
    - npm --version
    - export AWS_REGION=$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
    - export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=X 
    - export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=X
    - export DYNAMODB_LOCAL_ADDRESS=dynamodb
    - export S3_LOCAL_ADDRESS=localstack
    - npm install
    - npm run test-ci
  artifacts:
    when: always
    reports:
      junit:
        - serverless/junit/jest-junit.xml
      coverage_report:
        coverage_format: cobertura
        path: serverless/coverage/cobertura-coverage.xml

This is the bug trace in pipeline CICD :
$ apk add --no-cache aws-cli
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.20/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.20/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
ERROR: unable to select packages:
  aws-cli (no such package):
    required by: world[aws-cli]

Something change in the default docker image alpine of Gitlab Runner ?
Apart from pinning a version like this :
https://github-com.translate.goog/alpinelinux/docker-alpine/issues/396?_x_tr_sl=en&_x_tr_tl=fr&_x_tr_hl=fr&_x_tr_pto=sc
Is there another solution ?
Or waiting for a new Alpine version ?

aws-cli is not packaged within the apk repository, and aws-cli requires Python to be pre-installed.
You should download the aws-cli.zip bundle from aws package and follow their docs, you can use this script to install aws-cli which I used in Dockerfile.
RUN apk add bash curl git && apk add --update --no-cache python3 && ln -sf python3 /usr/bin/python && python3 -m ensurepip && pip3 install --no-cache --upgrade pip setuptools && curl "https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/awscli-bundle.zip" -o "awscli-bundle.zip" && unzip awscli-bundle.zip && ./awscli-bundle/install -i /usr/local/aws -b /usr/local/bin/aws
